# How to express elements of a DVR as power series of the uniformizer?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory, local-rings

Let $R$ be a DVR with a fixed uniformizer $t$. My main considering example is the local ring of an algebraic curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, so let's assume $R$ is a $k$-algebra and has the residue field isomorphic to $k$.

**ex-question:** Is it true that the $t$-adic completion of $R$ is isomorphic to $k[[t]]$?

**Update:** The answer is yes, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191725/completion-of-a-local-ring-of-a-curve.

So it remains the
**Main question:** How to explicitly write elements of $R$ as power series of $t$? In particular, how to write another uniformizer into a power series of $t$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $r \in R \cong k[\![t]\!]$. Let $v: R \to \mathbb N \cup \{ \infty \}$ denote the ($t$-adic) valuation. Then we have
$$
r = \sum_{i=v(r)}^\infty a_it^i,
$$
and if I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to find the $a_i$. This can be done recursively as follows. Let $p: R \to k$ be the projection to the residue field. Then we have $a_{v(r)} = p(r/t^{v(r)}) \in k$, and for $n > v(r)$,
$$
a_n = p\left((r - \sum_{i=v(r)}^{n-1}a_it^i)/t^n\right).
$$

Comment: First, it should be the completion of $R$, rather than $R$ itself, isomorphic to $k[[t]]$. Secondly, although this does give an algorithm to compute the coefficients, it is not effective enough. For instance, if you try to express t in terms of the uniformizer $\pi=(t+1)^n-1$. What I'm looking for is some kind of formula when I can write $R$ as the local ring of some affine curve $k[x,y,...]/I$.